# Grub-Customizer (How to fix your dual-boot in case you miss the right boot option)

Tags: boot, grub2

How can i fix my dual boot if i have selected the wrong one? P.ex. Grub-Customizer allow you to choose wich boot do you want when you turn your pc... but, how can i fix if i select the wrong choice!?

Comment: Boot cd with your Ubuntu (If you have Natty 11.04 you can simply use your 10.04 cd...)
try the experiment mode
Then install (as you have made in your system) Grub-Customizer packages (sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer && sudo apt-get update)
in update manager select the option "open source code software (Universal)"
In the terminal, install the packages (sudo apt-get install grub-customizer)
Acess to Grub and select root.Your boot option (in case you have dual or triple boot) will appear again

Comment: Instead of making your answer a comment, make it an answer and accept it (I think you need to wait two days before you can accept your own answer). :)

Comment: thnx. i'm new here n' i'm still trying to understand how this thing works.

Comment: We have [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) and [awesome video tutorials](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1037/video-tutorials-for-using-the-site/1038#1038) for new users. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(convert comment to answer)

Boot cd with your Ubuntu (If you have Natty 11.04 you can simply use your 10.04 cd...) try the experiment mode

Then install (as you have made in your system)

Grub-Customizer packages

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer && sudo apt-get update
```

in update manager select the option "open source code software (Universal)"

In the terminal, install the packages (`sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`)

Access to Grub and select root.

Your boot option (in case you have dual or triple boot) will appear again