# How to make Ubuntu as default OS

Tags: default

I tried to install Ubuntu on my ACER C7 Chromebook and I am using it now. I want to change it as my default OS but as I type the command:

```
sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 5 -S 1 /dev/sda
```

and then **"password user:"** appears and when I tried to type USER as the password, **it doesnt work.** I mean **I cant type it's as if the keyboard is not working.** I did this twice actually but got the same result. Please please please help me! T__T Thank you!

Comment: not sure where you are typing the password, but most of time you are typing a password into the terminal, it won't show any indication that you have typed anything on the screen. you just need to type the password out and hit enter...

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I did but its the same. :(

Comment: Yeah, i'm not really sure then, I don't have a setup like yours. I'm sorry. :0(

Comment: OK. :/ Thank you for answering anyways ^____^

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/930272/690724) and give it an upvote, _if it helps_! :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) with a live-usb ubuntu. See also the answer in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39605/grub-customizer-how-to-fix-your-dual-boot-in-case-you-miss-the-right-boot-optio) question